# Powerpoint VBA: How do I return a ShapeRange from inside a function? Error ShapeRange Failed

Tags: vba, powerpoint

$$ Select({Shape \in MySlide.Shapes: Some criterion}) $$

This is mathematical set-builder notation. Out of all shapes in the slide, select only those I want. I am building a Range-builder function,

... specifically to all shapes whose name start with some substring, but I got that part to work and it is beside the issue.
My issue is that my Range-builder function does not enjoy returning the ShapeRange it just built, and it frustrates me to no end.

Take a look at this:

```
Sub SelectShapes()
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.Range(Array(1, 2, 3)).Select
End Sub
```

This macro will correctly select shapes 1, 2 and 3 from slide 2 of my active presentation. Great!

Now I pretend to have a function calculate what shapes I want, and have *it* return the range

```
Sub SelectShapes()
    'ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.Range(Array(1, 2, 3)).Select
    MakeRange(ActivePresentation.Slides(2), Array(1, 2, 3)).Select
End Sub

Function MakeRange(SLIDE, WantedShapes)
    MakeRange = SLIDE.Shapes.Range(WantedShapes)
End Function
```

And then it trows the following error:

```
Error -2147467259 (80004005) during runtime:
Shapes.Range : Failed
```

Note that I am able to select the three shapes from inside the function

```
Sub SelectShapes()
    Debug.Print MakeRange(ActivePresentation.Slides(2), Array(1, 2, 3))
End Sub

Function MakeRange(SLIDE, WantedShapes)
    SLIDE.Shapes.Range(WantedShapes).Select
    MakeRange = True
End Function
```

This works absolutely fine.

Does anyone know why returning a shaperange does not work, and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `ShapeRange` is an object, it needs `Set`:

```
Function MakeRange( _
    ByVal Sld As Slide, _
    ByVal WantedShapes As Variant _
) As ShapeRange
    Set MakeRange = Sld.Shapes.Range(WantedShapes)
End Function
```

Also it is  better to be explicit: specify the variable types and the return type of the function.